# Angular $timeout - TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I wrote a directive and a service. The directive calls a timeout function in the service. However, once the $timeout is reached, it throws an error:

> TypeError: object is not a function

Original `$scope.msg` is not displayed. And the `$timeout` function does not wait for (20sec) to call the callback (or so I assume, since the `$scope.msg` changes right away).

I am absolutely lost. I found a few questions regarding timeouts, but none of them seem to have this problem. This one is as close as I got, and I am already following that answer [Angularjs directive TypeError: object is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547827/angularjs-directive-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function).

Here is a Plunker to the code: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/xrepQOWIHlccbW5atW88?p=preview

And here is the actual code.

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'myApp.services',
    'myApp.directives',
]);

angular.module('myApp.directives', []).
directive('logoutNotification', [
    function(admin) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: "<div>{{msg}}</div>",
            controller: ["$scope", "$timeout", "admin",
                function($scope, $timeout, admin) {
                    $scope.msg = "Hey, no timeout yet";
                    $scope.resetNotification = function() {
                        admin.resetNoticeTimer(function(){
                          $scope.msg = "Hey, I'm back from timeout"
                        });
                    };
                }
            ],
            link: function(scope) {
                scope.resetNotification();
            }
        };
    }
]);

angular.module('myApp.services', []).
factory('admin', ['$rootScope', '$location', '$timeout',
    function($rootScope, $timeout, $location, admin) {
        var noticeTimer;
        return {
            resetNoticeTimer: function(cb) {
                if (noticeTimer) {
                    $timeout.cancel(noticeTimer);
                }
                noticeTimer = $timeout(cb(), 20000);
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have misordered the dependencies.

Your code:

```
factory('admin', ['$rootScope', '$location', '$timeout',
    function($rootScope, $timeout, $location, admin) {
```

Should be:

```
factory('admin', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$location',
    function($rootScope, $timeout, $location) {
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I've spent 10+ hours on this now. Can't believe I missed that.